# avidemux: crop and increase sound volume

Tags: linux, command-line, audio, video, vlc-media-player

Arch Linux current:
This is my first use of avidemux. I have a .mp4 with 2 problems, video needs an irritating border cropped throughout, and the sound is barely audible at full volume setting.

Did the crop successfully with avidemux gui, but that seems to offer no way to increase sound volume (which I believe requires normalizing), so I cobbled together this command line from googling 'avidemux normalize'

```
avidemux3_cli --audio-process --audio-normalize --audio-resample 44100 --audio-codec MP3  --audio-bitrate 128 --video-codec X264  --output-format MP4 Muxer --force-alt-h264 --load WhiteDog_edit.mp4 --save WD.mp4 --quit
```

which produced a file that will not play, vlc having this to say about it

```
[096be080] pulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
[09627930] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xb562ad80] moov atom not found
[096ed0d0] skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
[096ed0d0] skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider
[096ed0d0] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.2.4 Weatherwax
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xb412c860] moov atom not found
[b4124430] avformat demux error: Could not open /home/q/WD.mp4: Unknown error 1094995529
[b415eee0] core demux error: option sub-original-fps does not exist
[b1800510] core input error: no suitable demux module for `file/subtitle:///home/q//wd.txt'
[b415ee70] core demux error: option sub-original-fps does not exist
[b1800510] core input error: demux doesn't like DEMUX_GET_TIME
... 6000+ times
[b1800510] core input error: demux doesn't like DEMUX_GET_TIME
[096ed0d0] [cli] lua interface error: Error loading script /usr/lib/vlc/lua /intf/cli.luac: lua/intf/modules/host.lua:279: Interrupted.
```

Advice please

Answer (score 2):

As avidemux apparently cannot do this, I took a different route, using the cropped file earlier produced with avidemux as input:
Extract video only with (%f is mc code for the input file-name)

```
ffmpeg -i %f -vcodec copy -an v.mp4
```

Extract audio to audiodump.wav

```
mplayer %f -benchmark -vc null -vo null -ao pcm:fast &> /dev/null
```

Increase the volume

```
sox -v 3.0 audiodump.wav awav
```

audiodump.wav is huge (as large, or more than the movie), so reencode it

```
lame -V2 a.wav a.mp3
```

Merge video and audio back together

```
ffmpeg -i v.mp4 -i a.mp3 -c copy m.mp4
```

And, of course, one can always find a better solution, a single ffmpeg command does it all. Again %f is the cropped file out of avidemux.

```
ffmpeg -i %f -c:v copy -c:a copy -vol 256 m.mp4
```

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu MATE. I had to install ffmpeg, sox, and lame, but they were all available via apt.